# How to copy a reference file to an agent system in TFS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I want to copy a file which has the verified results to the system having agent so that I can compare it with actual runtime data and create a result file. If both the file contents are same then the result is pass else it is fail.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the [DeploymentItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) attribute.  You decorate your TestMethod with it like this:

```cs
[TestMethod]
[DeploymentItem("testFile1.txt")]
public void ConstructorTest()
{
    // Create the file to deploy
    Car.CarInfo();
    string file = "testFile1.txt";
    // Check if the created file exists in the deployment directory
    Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(file), "deployment failed: " + file +
    " did not get deployed");
}
```

You'll also want to include the file (testFile1.txt) in your build somehow, so that the binary is dropped next to your test binary.  I usually just include the file in the solution, and then mark  "Copy to Output Directory" as "Copy if newer" in the properties.